# What happens to a property if its value is overwritten?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, nsstring, properties

Lets suppose I created a property tempStr that is of NSString type.
I synthesized it obviously.

In one of my methods, I set the value of tempstr to be yellowcolor.
Then just after that I reinitialized tempStr with redcolor.

So I wanna know what happens to the memory of tempStr in this case.

Thanx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what attribute you set for your property: `retain`, `assign` or `copy`.

- `@property (retain) NSString *tempStr`: the old value (yellowcolor) would be released and the new value (redcolor) would be retained. The only exception is when `yellowcolor == redcolor`. Then nothing would happen, because old and new values are the same.
- `@property (assign) NSString *tempStr`: there would be no release/retain operations. It is equal to changing just a pointer. So after this operations yellowcolor won't be released and you'll lost a reference to it (if there is no other reference to it in your code). So it can cause a memory leak.
- `@property (copy) NSString *tempStr`: it's similar to `retain` but it call `copy` on new value instead of just `retain`, so it'd create a duplicate object in a memory. Considering NSString, it's equal to `retain`, because NSString is immutable, so there is no need to make a duplicate.

You can find some code examples [here](http://www.cocoacast.com/?q=node/103).

**EDIT**: As @Bavarious mentioned, `copy` is equal to `retain` only if you initialize this property with `NSString`. It won't be equal if you initialize it with `NSMutableString`, because this one is mutable, so the "proper" copy would be make.

Comment: Note that an `NSString` property can be assigned as `NSMutableString` object, in which case `copy` doesn’t act as `retain`.

Answer (score 1):

A synthesized setter looks a bit like this:

```
- (void)setSomeString:(NSString *)newString
{
   if ([newString isEqualToString:someString]) return;

   [someString autorelease];
   someString = [newString copy]; // or [newString retain], depends how you defined the property ...
}
```

So the old value is released when the new value is assigned to the pointer.